# Draw a qlabel mirrored

Tags: android, qt, qlabel

I want to create a [HUD](http://s1.cdn.autoevolution.com/images/news/gms-full-windshield-hud-technology-explained-18454_3.jpg) speed counter using Qt and my smartphone. I can get speed via gps information, the issue is when I display it on the screen, I can't manage to display the QLabel mirrored.

So here's my question : Who can I write from right to left ?

Comment: Can this thread help you: http://www.qtcentre.org/archive/index.php/t-8248.html ?

Comment: Can't you align right your text?

Comment: @ariwez well played. You should post it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As asked by Samoth i post my comment as an answer ;)

This is helpful resource for mirroring QLabel: http://qtcentre.org/archive/index.php/t-8248.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it answers your question. The following resources demonstrate how to display RightToLeft Text in Qt / QLabel:

- [Qt 4.7 Desktop application support for right-to-left UI (Hebrew)](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/9448)
- [Display a Hebrew RTL label - howto?](http://www.qtforum.org/article/4600/display-a-hebrew-rtl-label-howto.html)

Comment: Well I think right to left was not the good words, I'll edit my question